# loop through string array java

Tags: java

Hi my code works but when it goes to the 2nd loop or iteration it does not input the next string name in the field, and I get a message saying (ElementNotInteractableException: Cannot click on element). The problem I think is that my For loop is not going through the list properly or not inputting them in the search field.

I tested and tested my code on its own and it works;it prints out all the names in the file. However, my only issue is that it is saying cannot click because it thinks that the string is being inputted, and it is not.

My am still learning Java and I think it is something small I am not doing. My code is below please help.

```
@Test 
public void step02_GetCycleInfo() throws Exception {  
    // loop through clientid test file
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("C:\\PayrollSync\\prepayroll.txt"));
    //String [] Arrayclients = content.split("\\s",0);
    String [] Arrayclients = content.split("\n");

    // begin for loop
    for(String client : Arrayclients) { 
        System.out.print(client);

        PP_OBJ_CycleData.verifysearch(driver);
        PP_OBJ_CycleData.searchbox(driver).clear();          
        PP_OBJ_CycleData.searchbox(driver).sendKeys(client);
        PP_OBJ_CycleData.searchbox(driver).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.linkText(client));
        dropdown.click();

        PP_OBJ_CycleData.practitioner(driver).click();
        PP_OBJ_CycleData.verifyProcessExists(driver);
        PP_OBJ_CycleData.Process(driver).click();
        PP_OBJ_CycleData.Payroll(driver).click();
        PP_OBJ_CycleData.PayrollSchedule(driver).click();

        PP_OBJ_CycleData.ReturnToSupport(driver);
    }//end for loop
```

Comment: did you check if your data file is correct? before doing anything debug and see size of `Arrayclients`

Comment: Yes I checked that already its fine

Comment: @Jonathan I'm confused by your question. You mention that you're getting an error after the second iteration, but that it prints all the names in the file. From your code it seems like the only way for the latter to be true is if it loops through all of the values of Arrayclients, not just the two times. Could you clarify?

Comment: Can you post a bit of stacktrace ? If the file and line count is fine, I don't think the error has anything to do with File IO part

Comment: After troubleshooting my code for hours i found out that my loop is ok it is working fine the problem is that java webdriver is not clicking on the dropdown text after it inputs it in the search field

Comment: after it inputs it in the search field....When I do xpath (.//span [contains text(), "+client+"]) it doesn't actually click on the drop down link so that practitioner access comes up. Its acting as if it clixk but did not.Note: i am.not at my pc soon might be writing the xpat the wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to utilize the variable.in xpath or linked. Please any help would be appreciated.